# Java Spring H2 database: error executing DDL via JDBC statement

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm trying to build a H2 database using Spring, but I'm running into errors. I've so far followed the steps from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYnM665A0EM&ab_channel=JasperZhao) channel, but I'm running into this error:

```
2022-12-30T22:04:01.054+11:00  WARN 18528 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "INSERT INTO courses VALUES (id, code, coursename) VALUES (1, 'CS150', 'Intro to Computer Science')" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "INSERT INTO courses VALUES (id, code, coursename) VALUES (1, 'CS150', 'Intro to Computer Science')" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
```

(the error continues...)

Model

```
package com.example.SpringPractice.model;

// imports

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String code;

    private String coursename;
}
```

Repository

```
package com.example.SpringPractice.repository;

import com.example.SpringPractice.model.Course;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, Long> {
}
```

Dependencies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Main

```
package com.example.SpringPractice;

// imports

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringPracticeApplication {

    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringPracticeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void postInit() {
        System.out.println("All courses: " + courseRepository.findAll());
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:course-db
```

SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO courses VALUES (id, code, coursename) VALUES (1, 'CS150', 'Intro to Computer Science')
```

I've tried changing what's in `application.properties`, dependencies (javax to jakarta).

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. The bottom "caused by" element will likely contain the actual error.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this was the error:
`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO courses VALUES (id, code, coursename) [*]VALUES (1, CS150, Intro to Computer Science)"; SQL statement:`

Thanks. I didn't even realise I had to look for "caused by".

I've got it working now by fixing the SQL statements to:
`INSERT INTO courses(id, code, coursename) VALUES (1, 'CS150', 'Intro to Computer Science')`

Comment: Ugh, I entirely read over the problem: remove the first `VALUES` from the statement. It should be `INSERT INTO course (id, code, coursename) VALUES (1, 'CS150', 'Intro to Computer Science')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake in the SQL statement. Facepalm..

I missed the "caused by" in the error logs which helped answer the problem.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO courses VALUES (id, code, coursename) [*]VALUES (1, CS150, Intro to Computer Science)"; SQL statement:
```

Fixed SQL statement with:

```
INSERT INTO courses(id, code, coursename) VALUES (1, 'CS150', 'Intro to Computer Science')
```

Comment: Please edit your original post instead of replying with an answer